# Accessing jQuery plugin data

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

The [jQuery documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) suggests storing additional info per DOMElement using [data()](http://api.jquery.com/data). But I'm having a hard time accessing the saved data in a good way.

The scope changes when I call other functions which makes me lose my way :)

```
(function ($) {
    var methods = {
        init: function (options) {
            return this.each(function () {
                var $this = $(this),
                    data = $this.data('myPlugin');

                if (!data) {
                    $(this).data('myPlugin', {
                        testValue: true
                    });

                    data = $this.data('myPlugin');
                }
            });
        },

        testFunction: function () {
            console.log('t: '+$(this).data('myPlugin').testValue);
            methods.otherFunction();
        },

        otherFunction: function () {
            console.log('o: '+$(this).data('myPlugin').testValue);
        }
    };

    $.fn.myPlugin = function (method) {
        if (methods[method]) {
            return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
            return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
        } else {
            $.error('Method ' + method + ' does not exist on jQuery.myPlugin');
        }
    };

})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').myPlugin();
    $('body').myPlugin('testFunction');
});
```

Console output:

```
t: true
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'testValue' of undefined
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use

```
        methods.otherFunction.apply(this);
```

instead of

```
        methods.otherFunction();
```

to make the scopes correct.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ayNUD/